# How to create dynamic edit option for static content in full static ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a Static Site with helps of Rails, Apart from this static site, I also created a Admin section from scratch, After logged in Admin have options to see name of static pages and option to edit these pages.

I already inserted new content manually using rails console, So dont need create content option on Admin section.

Now all static content for different static pages belongs to content_id = 1, Like:

```
{content id: "1", home: "blahblah", aboutus: "blahblah"}
```

I have Static pages controller to display contents to static pages, Sessions controller to manage Admin login and Contents controller to manage contents.

What ruby code should i write on app/view/contents/edit.html.erb and on Contents controller to effectivelly implement Edit option in Admin section?

Comment: why edited this question?

Comment: Actually Stackoverflow prohibited me to post new questions due to low quality,Not coherent questions, So i edited this one in the hope to uplift ban on me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you don´t want to have an extra area only for admin with extra views, controllers and so on? If that´s true, I´d recommend you to check out this gem: https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury

And here are further information/instructions about this gem: http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Comment: No, I wants to modify some codes on Contents controller so that admin can edit static content.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? You posted nearly a complete normal scaffold code in your question. Maybe your links are not correct? localhost:3000/contents/edit/1 - you can edit first static page..only thing that is missing in your code is a before_filter which handles the permissions..

Comment: Actually, if you see my db schema you can find out that all my static pages listed in contents table, So id=1 contain information for all static pages,so by visit this page localhost:3000/contents/edit/1 i cant edit all static pages separately, By the way i sort out the way to edit pages.Thanks for help

Comment: ah ok sorry, I understood your schema the false way. But why you create an extra attribute for each page.. Why not just one attribute called "headline", "text", "url" or something like that and than create content instances, or better call it page.. if you want to add a page in the future, you must update your whole schema, if you do it your way.. if you do it with normal instances, you can add as much pages as you like.without touching your db schema anymore..I think your schema really makes no sense this way. and btw edit_content_path(1) is not really nice. what if you drop your record once?